# Does a caster level bonus let our alchemist learn and use Fly at a lower level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

My level 5 alchemist got a Headband of Aerial Agility +2. The description of the item says:

> The wearer of a headband of aerial agility +2 treats his caster level as if it were one level higher when casting spells or creating extracts that grant flight.

Furthermore he has added the Fly spell into his formula book by learning from a Fly scroll.

Is it correct, that he can now create a Fly extract with the help of the headband and really fly around although he would not be able to create level 3 extracts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No

The [*headband of aerial agility*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-aerial-agility) will *not* allow you access to spells any earlier than you would normally have access to them.

What the item *will* do is allow you to remain flying longer once you *can* create a *fly* extract

For example, a level 7 alchemist who creates the *fly* extract can fly for 1 min./level (therefore 7 minutes). When wearing the *headband*, that alchemist is considered level 8 for effects relating to caster level regarding the spell *fly*. In this case, that means flying for 8 minutes instead of 7.